# Java play framework Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am a beginner in java play framework, I try to use Mysql in application.conf but i get an error: Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you added the mysql driver as a dependency to your project?

Comment: I added it but after in build.sbt like this:   cache,
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.13"   , but now i get an error : expected but eof found.
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.13"

Comment: can you add relevant lines of your build.sbt (ie full dependecies declaration)?

Comment: name := "bid"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"

)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings

Comment: @KaberaMugwanezaAlexis edit your answer and post the content of your `build.sbt`. Posting it as a comment makes it difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

according to [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDatabase#MySQL-database-engine-connection-properties) you have to use it like that :

```
# Default database configuration using MySQL database engine
# Connect to playdb as playdbuser
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/playdb"
db.default.username=playdbuser
db.default.password="a strong password"
```

so it seems that you used it right. Problem is very likely in your dependencies declaration (according to your comment)

Comment: Thanks, but i don't wonder if before using mysql in play it requires some mysql libraries ? what what that 5.1.18 means in build.sbt ?

Comment: it is the version of the connector you are going to use. As far as I know the "mysql libraries" you are talking about is this connector. see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java for example

Comment: Thanks , let me try it and i see

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, the mysql connector library needs to be added in `build.sbt` as well. It's annoying this is only mentioned in the very end of the [play JDBC connection documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDatabase#Configuring-the-JDBC-Driver-dependency)

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is deprecated. Try driver class  `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` instead.